# Why don't I see the "Add to Homescreen" option on iOS 11.2

Tags: ios, localhost, ios-simulator, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I am testing the offline PWA features of a web app. Using the 9.3 simulator, I simply click the "share" button, then "Add to Homescreen".

Using the 11.2 simulator, there is no "Add to Homsecreen" button. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was going to delete the question, but just in case someone else made this mistake...I'll instead, point out the problem I had.

The only issue I had was that the new version has more options in the Share menu so that the "Add to Homescreen" button was offscreen. I only had to scroll to the right to see it!

Answer (score 0):

There is NO selection for "Add to Home Screen" on IOS12.   None.   I had found an app that enabled this but I accidentally deleted it and cannot find it.   When I installed it I could add anything to my home screen.

Comment: The OP was referring to iOS 11.2, 12

Comment: I am using iOS 12.x and the option is there.  Note that it is available in Safari. I can't speak to Chrome or other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the shortcuts app downloaded on your phone for it to work :) just figured that out!